# How to create a scrollbar that dynamically changes the content of widget inside the Canvas? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am creating a program that displays the data in a tabular form(something like excel). [Inside Canvas with scrollbar] every new entry create a new row_frame as the data gets bigger the app crashes as there are too many widgets.

So I was hoping to create fixed amount of row_frame and change the data of each row_frame with the scrollbar....

Or anything that works.

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: This question is far too broad for stackoverflow. The scrollbar has a published API, which you can use to compute the number of visible rows and which row is at the top.

Comment: Why Canvas? [Treeview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview)

Comment: @Sujay I don't think my code is relevant to what I am asking.

Comment: @8349697 I need to add widgets[eg. button] in the row_frame.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you give me some more details or provide some other source.

Comment: @SleepySamaZZZ Scrollbar description: [ttk.Scrollbar](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Scrollbar.html), [ttk.Scrollbar - Tcl/Tk](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_scrollbar.htm), [tk.Scrollbar](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/scrollbar.html), [Scrollbar - Tcl/Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/scrollbar.html), [Scrollable Widget Options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#scrollable-widget-options), [Examples (Python 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808121645/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)

Comment: Option: Create a fixed table of, say, 100 rows. And create a "Next" button to update the canvas with every new piece of data.

Comment: Thanks every one for the help , I did manage to sneak in a way but my main_frame(where I stores all the row_frame) gave out on about 32,742 pixels height. I don't know if it's my own code's error or there is fixed maximum heights for frames.